# Emeditor : When using the extract feature : how to also remove the extracted contents (rows) from the source document?

Tags: text-extraction, emeditor

*Example :* the file "A.txt" contains several rows with phrases :

```
This is a phrase
Bla keyword blabla
This is another phrase
```

*Desired results :*

*in A.txt :*

```
This is a phrase
This is another phrase
```

*in B.txt :*

```
Bla keyword blabla
```

Then I use the option "Find" keyword then I use "Extract". It extracts the correct rows in a new document (B.txt) but how to also remove the full row(s) containing the selected keyword in "A.txt" ?

Comment: What is a keyword in this example?

Comment: The keyword is keyword in this example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with EmEditor. I have provided two methods.

**Method 1**

1. Select a `keyword`, right-click on the selection, and select **Filter Out**.

[image: Filter Out]

2. Click **Extract All** on the **Filter** toolbar.

[image: Extract All]

3. Save as a new file name.

**Method 2**

1. Select a `keyword`, right-click on the selection, and select **Filter**.
2. Make sure **Block Multiline Changes** is disabled on the **Filter** toolbar.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all text.
4. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.
5. Click the **Abort** button on the **Filter** toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing a lot in EmEditor and using only the keyboard, this is the quickest way I know.

Here are my steps:

1. Highlight the `search string` and open the **Find** dialogue <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to **Extract** the lines into a new document/tab
3. <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the **Find** dialogue (not needed if option **Close when finished** in the Find dialogue is active).
4. Go back to the original source document <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>
5. Re-open the **Find** dialogue <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
6. Bookmark the lines <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
7. <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the **Find** dialogue (not needed if option **Close when finished** in the Find dialogue is active).
8. Delete the bookmarked lines <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Steps 3 and 7 can be skipped if using the mouse to select the original source document. I just haven't figured how to activate it with the keyboard while the **Find** window is still open.